# Chrome extension: Get charset of current page

Tags: character-encoding, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

How can I tell **within the background code** with which charset the current page is defined.

More specifically: I'm using context menu and I want to know whether the selected text is encoded in utf-8 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this without [`content scripts`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), but you can do it with minimal permissions by using [`activeTab`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html) and [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). It would look something like this:

**manifest.json**

```css
"permissions": [
  "activeTab","contextMenus"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
    {code:"function getCharset(){return document.charset;}getCharset();"},
    function(results){
       // results[0] will now contain the charset for the page in question
    });
});
```